How can I install scikit-learn from source using my locally modified clone
I have made modifications to the scikit-learn codebase that I want to test locally, but when I run pytest, I get the error "scikit-learn is not built correctly".
So I try to build it by following the developer instructions, by using this
$ pip install --editable . --verbose --no-build-isolation --config-settings editable-verbose=true

but this does not work. Any other way to build scikit-learn?
This what I tried:
I downloaded vs_buildtools.exe with "Desktop development with C++". Then
C:> SET DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1
C:> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64

I used "Microsoft Visual Studio 2022" instead of "Microsoft Visual Studio 2019". Then,
$ pip install --editable . --verbose --no-build-isolation --config-settings editable-verbose=true


Did you create a conda environment as recommended by the page your reference? Conda will install the compiler for you, prebuilt and preconfigured, making this a lot easier than trying to download and install the compiler from the Microsoft web pages.

I find that for anything Python that requires compilation, on Windows it's really a lot easier to work with Conda that otherwise: you'll save yourself hours of troubleshooting. I know it's all possible without conda, it's just harder to get it right.
